# How to get the touch effect as in the word search games

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: Refer this image]

I know how to set `ontouchlistener` on a button. I can touch `linearlayout` and move my finger on it but that finger does not detect the touch on buttons. it seems as I touch the buttons but actually I am touching `linearlayout`. how can I touch the buttons placed on linear layout in sequence.

```
layoutVertical.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int actionPeformed = event.getAction();

        switch (actionPeformed) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();

                lastXAxis = x;
                lastYAxis = y;

                textView2.setText("Button pressed");
                //buttons[0][0].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                    }
                }


                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();

                final float dx = x - lastXAxis;
                final float dy = y - lastYAxis;
                ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                xAxis += dx;
                yAxis += dy;
                ed4.setText(Float.toString(yAxis));
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                textView2.setText("released");
                buttons[0][0].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
                //drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
                drawable.setStroke(2, Color.MAGENTA);
                drawable.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                buttons[rows][cols].setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                mp.pause();
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Let me see if I got your question right, you want your linear layout to pass touch events to your buttons ?

Comment: I think better approach to create a game like word search is to create a custom view divide that view(screen) in mxn dimension then play with onTouchListner of that view and draw coloring by using canvas.